# Calculate bounce rate with Clickhouse

Tags: sql, time-series, clickhouse

I am trying to use Clickhouse for a small analytics app of mine and I have a table that records raw hits as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE hits (
  sessionId LowCardinality(String),
  page LowCardinality(String),
  timestamp DateTime,
  projectId UInt16
) ENGINE = MergeTree() PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(timestamp)
ORDER BY (projectId, page, toStartOfHour(timestamp)) --
  SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

Afterwards I can add some sample data as:

```sql
sessionId page    timestamp            projectId 
xxx       /       2021-03-12 13:51:12  1         
yyy       /       2021-03-12 13:51:12  1         
xxx       /cool   2021-03-12 13:52:12  1         
fff       /       2021-03-12 13:53:12  1
```

What I am trying to achieve is calculating bounces (unique sessionId occurunce) and views per page, something like:

```sql
page   bounces views projectId
/      2       3     1
/cool  0       1     1
```

I can easily count the views per page but the unique `sessionId` counting is failing due to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT page,
  projectId,
  count(*) as views,
  count(DISTINCT sessionId) as bounces --fail
from hits
GROUP BY (page, projectId);
```

Any ideas, workarounds on changing the Clickhouse schema or even using some of engine from Clickhouse for aggregation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your table hits is incorrect. Why MergeTree has  AggregateFunction? MergeTree wont collapse AggregateFunction.

Comment: What  is the test.fooagr ?

Comment: use `uniqExact(sessionId)` or better `uniq(sessionId)` instead of `count(DISTINCT sessionId)`

Comment: Hey @DennyCrane, `AggregateFunction` and `test.fooagr` where typos due to bad copy-pasting and trying to simplify the snippets. 

Using `uniq(sessionId)` or `count(DISTINCT sessionId)` does not count bounces as the `sessionId` occurs in another group since I want found out which pages have the most bounces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/parametric-functions/#function-sequencecount

```
select projectId, p[1] page, countIf(length(p)=1) bounce
from (
SELECT 
  projectId, sessionId,
  groupArray( page ) p
from hits
GROUP BY sessionId, projectId )
group by projectId,page
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for the answer, it actually works like a charm. I took a look at `sequenceCount` but I am not quite sure how it can be used with parametric values. Would you mind updating the answer with an example?